# Is 98.6 degrees F the true normal average temperature?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have a file containing a sample of body temperatures from both men and women where the average temperature is about 98.25 degrees F, I wanna know if 98.6 degrees F is the "true normal". I'm not really sure what is meant by "true normal" but I'm supposed to apply a some statistical hypothesis test to solve it. Do anyone know what is meant by true normal and if so suggest how I could apply a statistical test, Thank you.

Comment: You could do a hypothesis test for the mean of the population you sampled from. Alternative hypothesis: the mean is not 98.6.

Comment: Our body temperature actually follows a cycle throughout the day. The temperature on average oscillates between $97.7^oF$ and $99.5^oF$. The place and method of measurement also leads to variation in results.

Comment: So could I perhaps make a students t-test to test the null hypothesis that the sample comes from a distribution with a mean = 98.6?

Comment: Yes, that's right, you could do a $t$-test.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! @littleO

Comment: If this is a real question rather than to practice statistics, there have been suggestions that average human temperatures have been falling over the last century as health has improved, and that $37^\circ C = 98.6^\circ F$ is too high for the contemporary average; this does not change the threshold for a fever, but recognises there are fewer fevers.